# ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 not displaying some characters such as vertical bar and open parenthesis

Tags: antlrworks

Forgive me if this question has been asked and addressed elsewhere on this site. When I type in a sample grammar in ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, the editor does not display some characters such as the vertical bar ('|') or the open parenthesis '('. I noticed that somewhere in this site Maya Posch asked a question on extended ASCII characters not being handled properly but I seem to have a different situation. When I type in a sample grammar from the tutorial, I can't see those characters in the editor screen. However, the syntax chart below the editor pane seems to recognize the existence of those 'missing' characters. The following is the grammar (strangely, when I copy and paste here, they show up as in the following!):

```
grammar Expr;

// START:stat
prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE
    |   NEWLINE
    ;
// END:stat

// START:expr
expr:   multExpr (('+'|'-') multExpr)*
    ; 

multExpr
    :   atom ('*' atom)*
    ; 

atom:   INT 
    |   ID
    |   '(' expr ')'
    ;
// END:expr

// START:tokens
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
INT :   '0'..'9'+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+ {skip();} ;
// END:tokens
```

Here's what I see in the editor:

```
grammar Expr;

// START:stat
prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE
        ID '=' expr NEWLINE
        NEWLINE
    ;
// END:stat

// START:expr
expr:   multExpr  '+' '-') multExpr)*
    ; 

multExpr
    :   atom '*' atom)*
    ; 

atom:   INT 
        ID
        '(' expr ')'
    ;
// END:expr

// START:tokens
ID  :   'a'..'z' 'A'..'Z')+ ;
INT :   '0'..'9'+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS  :   ' ' '\t')+ {skip);} ;
// END:tokens
```

The code looks jumbled because the vertical bar and open parenthesis characters are not visible in the editor pane. But when I copy the text from the editor to a code segment on this posting, those missing characters do show up as I posted above originally. However, the literal open parenthesis ('(') does remain visible. Could this be a configuration issue for the editor?

When I generate the code, everything works just fine. Also, the syntax diagram correctly displays the rule. It's just the missing/invisible characters in the grammar rule that is troubling. I am running ANTLRWorks on a MacBook Pro.

Edit: As suggested by Bart, I tried a different font and those invisible characters do show in the editor pane. I went into the preferences page, and changed the font to something else other than the default Courier New. My computer is a MacBook Pro so this could be specific to the Mac environment. Hope this helps others experiencing the same problem. Thanks, Bart!

Comment: I see nothing odd about that grammar (or the characters in it). What exactly do you mean by *"does not display some characters"*: is the entire character not visible in the editor area, or is it not visible in the syntax diagram tab? A screenshot would help. What happens if you generate a lexer & parser from the grammar?

Comment: Editing the original post was the right thing to do. Thanks. However, I don't think I can help you much: I've never heard of the problem you mention. All I can come up with is you try a different version of ANTLRWorks or change the font and/or font size in ANTLRWorks to see if that helps... Good luck!

Comment: John, you can add new information to your original post, and such small updates as you just posted can best be added as a comment (as this one). Note that if you find the solution, it's perfectly fine to answer your own question. Best of luck!

Comment: John, glad to hear you resolved it! Could you perhaps move your solution into a real answer? If people now scan your question (without reading to the end) and scroll down to the answers-section, they might think the problem is unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: You can reply to comments by posting your own comment, there is "add comment" link below each post..

Answer (score 2):

I have also suffered this problem and after change ANTLR-works font in configuration menu, now all characters show correctly. I have changed font to monospaced 14 points.