# Q&A: ANTLRWorks 3.0 mac os version some symbol (like vertical bar '|' ) disappear/not show correctly issue

Tags: macos, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks, antlrv3ide

Someone just like me found that it is hard to use ANTLRWorks 3.0 under Mac OS, some symbols typically vertical bar '|' is invisible . it is because default mac front is not compatible in this IDE,this is the way to fix this issue:

```
see answer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 not displaying some characters such as vertical bar and open parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885578/antlrworks-1-4-3-not-displaying-some-characters-such-as-vertical-bar-and-open-pa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.click 'ANTLRWorks' in menue bar 
2.Select 'Preferences'
3.Select 'Editor'
4.you can see 'Font:' in the first line of 'Editor' page
5.Change Front , e.g I use Dialog 
6.Problem fixed.
```